# Functioning scrapy spider now dies after one request?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I had a functioning scrapy spider and now it is dying after just one request? I cant figure out what is happening. I have posted the complete output when it finishes and my spider code.

```
jeff@deltaskelta:~/Desktop/hangulscrape/hangulscrape$ scrapy crawl englishwiki -o test.json
2015-01-13 22:20:41+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: hangulscrape)
2015-01-13 22:20:41+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2015-01-13 22:20:41+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'hangulscrape.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'test.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['hangulscrape.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'hangulscrape', 'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeue.FifoMemoryQueue', 'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeue.PickleFifoDiskQueue'}
2015-01-13 22:20:42+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [englishwiki] INFO: Spider opened
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [englishwiki] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6036
2015-01-13 22:20:43+0900 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6093
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_warbler> (referer: None)
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'en.wikipedia.org': <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_warbler>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.mediawiki.org': <GET https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:TimedMediaHandler/Client_download>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.iucnredlist.org': <GET http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22716906>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'dx.doi.org': <GET http://dx.doi.org/10.1111%2Fj.1463-6409.2006.00221.x>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov': <GET http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1794596>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.birdlife.org': <GET http://www.birdlife.org/datazone/speciesfactsheet.php?id=8074>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.jstor.org': <GET http://www.jstor.org/stable/4454>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'blx1.bto.org': <GET http://blx1.bto.org/birdfacts/results/bob12760.htm>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.webcitation.org': <GET http://www.webcitation.org/6HLrPClx6>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.euring.org': <GET http://www.euring.org/data_and_codes/longevity-voous.htm>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.tandfonline.com': <GET http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00063657909476637>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.nhm.ac.uk': <GET http://www.nhm.ac.uk/research-curation/scientific-resources/biodiversity/uk-biodiversity/british-flea-distribution/database/Searchpage.do?county=&fleaname=&host=&hostname=Garden+Warbler&listoption=&publication=&search=Search&sortorder=&species=>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.biodiversitylibrary.org': <GET http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/88617>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'oops.uni-oldenburg.de': <GET http://oops.uni-oldenburg.de/214/>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'commons.wikimedia.org': <GET http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ibc.lynxeds.com': <GET http://ibc.lynxeds.com/species/garden-warbler-sylvia-borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ornithos.de': <GET http://www.ornithos.de/Ornithos/Feather_Collection/Sylvia_borin/Sylvia_borin.htm>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'donate.wikimedia.org': <GET https://donate.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FundraiserRedirector?uselang=en&utm_campaign=C13_en.wikipedia.org&utm_medium=sidebar&utm_source=donate>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'shop.wikimedia.org': <GET http://shop.wikimedia.org/>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.wikidata.org': <GET http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q202478>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'kbd.wikipedia.org': <GET http://kbd.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8D%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%8A%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B6%D1%8D>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'af.wikipedia.org': <GET http://af.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuinsanger>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ar.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AF%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%8A%D9%86>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ba.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ba.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%BA%D0%B0%D2%99_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'bg.wikipedia.org': <GET http://bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'br.wikipedia.org': <GET http://br.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devedig-liorzh>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ca.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallarol_gros>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ceb.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ceb.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'cs.wikipedia.org': <GET http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%9Bnice_slav%C3%ADkov%C3%A1>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'cy.wikipedia.org': <GET http://cy.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telor_yr_Ardd>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'da.wikipedia.org': <GET http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havesanger>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'de.wikipedia.org': <GET http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gartengrasm%C3%BCcke>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'et.wikipedia.org': <GET http://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aed-p%C3%B5%C3%B5salind>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'es.wikipedia.org': <GET http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'eo.wikipedia.org': <GET http://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%9Cardensilvio>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'eu.wikipedia.org': <GET http://eu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baso-txinbo>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'fa.wikipedia.org': <GET http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A2%D9%84%D9%88%DA%86%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B1%DA%A9>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'fo.wikipedia.org': <GET http://fo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gar%C3%B0lj%C3%B3mari>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'fr.wikipedia.org': <GET http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fauvette_des_jardins>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'gl.wikipedia.org': <GET http://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papuxa_picafollas>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'hy.wikipedia.org': <GET http://hy.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D4%B1%D5%B5%D5%A3%D5%B8%D6%82_%D5%B7%D5%A1%D5%B0%D6%80%D5%AB%D5%AF>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'io.wikipedia.org': <GET http://io.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekafiko>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'it.wikipedia.org': <GET http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'he.wikipedia.org': <GET http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'kk.wikipedia.org': <GET http://kk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D2%9B_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D2%93%D0%B0%D1%88>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'kv.wikipedia.org': <GET http://kv.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%8D%D1%82%D3%A7%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B9>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'lt.wikipedia.org': <GET http://lt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodin%C4%97_devynbals%C4%97>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'li.wikipedia.org': <GET http://li.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zengersj_van_de_Ouwe_Waereld>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'hu.wikipedia.org': <GET http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerti_posz%C3%A1ta>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'mk.wikipedia.org': <GET http://mk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ms.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burung_siul_taman>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'nl.wikipedia.org': <GET http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuinfluiter>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'nap.wikipedia.org': <GET http://nap.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucetula>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'no.wikipedia.org': <GET http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagesanger>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'nn.wikipedia.org': <GET http://nn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagesongar>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ps.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ps.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%BC%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'pms.wikipedia.org': <GET http://pms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'pl.wikipedia.org': <GET http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaj%C3%B3wka_(ptak)>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'pt.wikipedia.org': <GET http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felosa-das-figueiras>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ru.wikipedia.org': <GET http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'sl.wikipedia.org': <GET http://sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrtna_penica>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'fi.wikipedia.org': <GET http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehtokerttu>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'sv.wikipedia.org': <GET http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A4dg%C3%A5rdss%C3%A5ngare>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'tr.wikipedia.org': <GET http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boz_%C3%B6tle%C4%9Fen>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'uk.wikipedia.org': <GET http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'vi.wikipedia.org': <GET http://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'war.wikipedia.org': <GET http://war.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_borin>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'creativecommons.org': <GET http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'wikimediafoundation.org': <GET http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.wikimediafoundation.org': <GET http://www.wikimediafoundation.org/>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'en.m.wikipedia.org': <GET http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile&title=Garden_warbler>
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 234,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 36442,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 13, 20, 47, 424202),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 74,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'offsite/domains': 71,
     'offsite/filtered': 289,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 13, 20, 43, 114492)}
2015-01-13 22:20:47+0900 [englishwiki] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is the spider code:

```
import scrapy
from hangulscrape.items import HangulScrapeItem
import re
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import json


class HangulSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name='englishwiki'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org/wiki/']
    start_urls = [
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_warbler'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_it', follow=True),
        )

    def parse_it(self, response):

        the_item = HangulScrapeItem()
        response.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').extract()

        english_dict = {}
        for i in body:
            english_words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z\'-]+' ,i)
            if english_words:
                for j in english_words:
                    if len(j) > 1:
                        word = j.lower()
                        if word in english_dict:
                            english_dict[word] += 1
                        else:
                            english_dict[word] = 1

        jsondump = json.dumps(english_dict)
        the_item['word'] = jsondump
        the_item['site'] = response.url

        return the_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you delete:

```
allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org/wiki/']
```

You will allow the spider to load domains that are not en.wikipedia.org/wiki.

This log message shows the domain filtering that is happening:

DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'dx.doi.org':

It is filtering the offsite requests, i.e. not letting the spider crawl them.

Comment: The problem was not inside the allowed_domains. Otherwise scrapy would be unstoppable and scrape all wikipedia. if you check debug log the spider got the right page but was unable to parse it (message Crawled 0 pages)

Comment: Yes, I put the allowed domains to wikipedia.org/wiki on purpose because I wanted to crawl through only the wiki pages that are all linked to each other. What would stop the spider from parsing it? Especially when it used to work? And even stranger, when I change the domain it crawls ok...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate all your code since items are missing. In any case here it is a simplified version of your code:

- changed the parse function
- not present items and conversion by json

  ```
  class testSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name='englishwiki'
      allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_warbler"]
      start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_warbler"]
      rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse', follow=True),)
      def parse(self, response):
          response.body.decode('utf-8')
          body = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()').extract()

          english_dict = {}
          for i in body:
              english_words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z\'-]+' ,i)
              if english_words:
                  for j in english_words:
                      if len(j) > 1:
                          word = j.lower()
                          if word in english_dict:
                              english_dict[word] += 1
                          else:
                              english_dict[word] = 1
          print english_dict
  ```

output:

> 1, u'times': 1, u'length': 2, u'south': 5, u'upperparts': 4, u'isbn':
>   19, u'evans': 1, u'scene': 1, u'reaches': 1, u'svalbard': 1,
>   u'management': 1, u'atricapilla': 1, u'their': 15, u'vocalisation': 1,
>   u'intermediate': 1, u'zoologica': 1, u'shell': 1, u'accompany': 1,
>   u'july': 1, u'ben': 2, u'borini': 1, u'protista': 1, u'sweden': 2,
>   u'migration': 15, u'clip': 2, u'have': 17, u'throat': 1, u'able': 1,
>   u'relatives': 1, u'which': 13, u'vegetation': 2, u'digestive': 1,
>   u'sylviae': 1, u'alarmed': 1, u'class': 1, u'afresh': 1,
>   u'conspecifics': 2, u"dohrn's": 1, u'spleen': 1, u'clive': 1,
>   u'jean-louis': 1, u'sylviid': 1, u'painting': 1, u'phenology': 2,
>   u'warblers': 31, u'selection': 1, u'biebach': 2, u'text': 1,
>   u'supported': 1, u'nagy': 1, u'longevity': 1, u'fear': 1, u'pause': 1,
>   u'interspecific': 3, u'should': 1, u'jan': 1, u'bernard': 1,
>   u'arabian': 1, u'piano': 1, u'local': 2, u'means': 2, u'borin': 16,
>   u'areas': 6, u'organ': 2, u'she': 1, u'nightingale': 1, u'available':
>   1, u'mid-september': 1, u'edition': 1, u'boddaert': 7, u'oldenburg':
>   2, u'placed': 2, u'pattern': 1, u'southward': 2, u'identification': 2,
>   u'closed': 4, u'bedfordshire': 1, u'simms': 3, u'kidneys': 1,
>   u'publishers': 1, u'animalia': 1, u'miroslav': 1, u'jon': 2,
>   u'seventeen': 1, u'olga': 1, u'april': 4, u'sexes': 1, u'passing': 1,
>   u'grounds': 3, u'ch': 1, u'cm': 6, u'reorientating': 1,
>   u'coexistence': 1, u"cock's": 1, u'johann': 1, u'fledging': 1,
>   u'anthelme': 1, u'table': 1, u'second': 1, u'silvia': 1, u'quia': 1,
>   u'long-tailed': 2

Comment: But i believe that still only makes one request, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It was that I was trying to specify a subdirectory of a domain in the domains section. It appears that domains and subdomains are ok, but subdirectories are not.

So (en.wikipedia.org = good) and (en.wikipedia.org/wiki = bad)

The correct place to specify how to pull links would be in the rules for extracting links.